# Apex Inbound email class for Lightning

Tags: apex-email-service

We are currently moving to Field service lightning, we have Apex email services which uses  Messaging.InboundEmailHandler instance to auto creates service cases from incoming emails from our customers. I tried creating cases through email in FSL sandbox but it won't create any cases, I don't even see any trace in the debug logs and the surprising part is, when ever I try to create a case, it is actually trying to create cases in our old classic sandbox (based on debug logs). How do I tackle it? 80% of our cases are created currently through through Apex email services.

Comment: *I tried creating cases through email in FSL sandbox but it won't create any cases* -- are you sending the email to the correct email address as specified in the Apex Email Service?

Comment: Yes.. Everything's perfect... Here it doesn't specify anything about lightning..
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_inbound_email.htm&type=5

Comment: *when ever I try to create a case, it is actually trying to create cases in our old classic sandbox (based on debug logs)* -- what is that in your debug log which hints that it is trying to create in a different sandbox?

Comment: EmailtoApexHandler operation. If case is created, I would get success message, if it fails, I would get List index out of bounds error. One thing for sure is I can't make it to run on FSL sandbox.

Comment: I think you'll need to include some of the code from the service to get help with this. I'd suggest it's either a permissions/access issue or a bug in the code.